# Cumulative Distribution Function CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. Given $0 < \alpha < 1$, we generate a random variable $Y$ as follows: If $X_1 > \alpha$, then $Y = X_1$. Otherwise $Y = X_2$.
(a) What are the CDF and PDF of $Y$.
My question:
If $X_1 > \alpha$ this implies that $X_1$ is greater than $1$, but $X_1$ is bounded by $1$, so the interval therefore contains $1$ point, which is $1$. With the same logic, the interval for $X_2$ would just be the point $0$. 
This does not seem correct, since if we are asked to compute the PDF we should have a interval. But I don't understand how we will obtain an interval from the restrictions of the domain.

Comment: "If X1 > α this implies that X1 is greater than 1." This is false.

Comment: $$f_Y=\alpha\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}+\mathbf 1_{(\alpha,1)}$$

Comment: Your question says "$\alpha < 1$".  It also says $0 < \alpha$.  So $\alpha \lt X_1 \lt 1$ is possible and has a positive probability

Comment: @Henry Is the following correct?  α < X1 <= 1 and 0 <= X2 <= α, thus we can express X1 and X2 as Y=X1+X2 and this is now a convolution problem?

Comment: @andreawong Where you got sum of random variables? And $X_2$ is not bounded by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDF of $Y$ find using $\{X_1\leqslant \alpha\}\cup\{X_1>\alpha\}=\Omega$ and this events are disjoint:
$$
\begin{multline}
F_Y(y)=\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) = \mathbb P(Y\leqslant y, X_1\leqslant \alpha)+\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y, X_1> \alpha)= \\ =\mathbb P(X_2\leqslant y, X_1\leqslant \alpha)+\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant y, X_1> \alpha)=\mathbb P(X_2\leqslant y)\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant \alpha)+\mathbb P(\alpha<X_1\leqslant y)
\end{multline}
$$
Consider  $y<0$, $y\geqslant 1$, $\alpha<y<1$ and $0\leqslant y\leqslant\alpha$ separately and write CDF. After find PDF and check whether you got the same as [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) wrote in comment above.